# A link callback to a MediaWiki extension

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

What is the most practical way of calling back into an extension from a link in the MediaWiki UI?

I have an extension that will add a link (e.g. "Report") in the history and diff pages, that needs run code in my extension.

Is it possible to have a "generic" callback URL (e.g. `index.php/PageName?action=report&edit=123`) or will I need to create a full special page (index.php/Special:Report?edit=123`) to handle this an execute my own code?
There won't be any more UI after this beyond reporting success or failure.

Answer (score 2):

Both of those are possible.

- To define a custom action like `action=report`, define a subclass of the [Action class](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/html/classAction.html) and add it to [`$wgActions`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgActions).  (There's also an [UnknownAction hook](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/UnknownAction) that can be used for the same purpose, but it's considered deprecated.)
- To define a new special page, you need to create a subclass of [SpecialPage](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/html/classSpecialPage.html) and add it to [`$wgSpecialPages`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgSpecialPages).  There's a lot more information at [Manual:Special pages](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aSpecial_pages) on mediawiki.org.

There's also a third option you might want to consider:

- MediaWiki extensions can [define custom API modules](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aExtensions) by subclassing [ApiBase](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/html/classApiBase.html) and adding it to [`$wgAPIModules`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgAPIModules).  Such API modules can then be invoked using [AJAX code](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aAjax) injected into the page by your extension (e.g. using [ResourceLoader](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader/Developing_with_ResourceLoader)), and they can report the success of failure of the action back using JSON.

Calling a custom API module via AJAX could offer a better user experience than just a plain link to a success / error page.  For accessibility, though, you may want to provide *both* methods, so that your extension remains usable even for users without JavaScript support, or with JavaScript disabled.  This is generally best done by writing your SpecialPage / Action and ApiBase subclasses as thin wrappers around a shared backend.